to many requests when running OpenAI API
I'm running a small test for the OpenAI API, but I keep encountering this error:
Error
In the Dashboard there is nothing displayed:
Dashboard1
Dashboard2
Here's the code snippet I'm using:
const handleChatGPT = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await openai.chat.completions.create({
      model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
      messages: [
        { role: "system", content: "You are a poetic assistant, skilled in explaining complex programming concepts with creative flair." },
        { role: "user", content: "Compose a poem that explains the concept of recursion in programming." },
      ],
    });
    console.log("successful");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
};

I've tried different user API keys and project API keys but nothing worked, always the same 4 logs

This question is similar to: OpenAI API giving error: 429 Too Many Requests. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
